# Simple linear regression model with random x

Tags: regression

I am looking for mathematical derivation of intercept and slope of simple linear regression model when the independent variable is random (not fixed). I.e., follows normal distribution or else.
I want to check the impact of random x on the slope and intercept estimates and their variances.

Comment: This is part of the standard formulation of ordinary least squares, provided $X$ is independent of the errors in $Y$: all the estimates and variances are conditional on $X$.  That enables you to assume any marginal distribution you want for $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot whuber.... Yes i got it..... If i assumed normal distribution for X.... Can you share with me mathematical derivation or some reference for this....

Comment: I need some mathematical explanation for my problems.... Can some one help me for this....